# Marshal structure to pointer then pointer to unicode string VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, character-encoding, marshalling

Our client has a requirement to move data from a structure into a string so that it can be shipped off to the mainframe.  Our process coming in is basically marshaling the data from string into the structure, this part was easy...

I'm trying to do the reverse now and am running into some difficulties.  Here is the test structure I'm working with.

```
 <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)> _
Public Structure Contact
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=50)> _
    Public Address As String
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=20)> _
    Public FirstName As String
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=20)> _
    Public LastName As String
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=12)> _
    Public PhoneNumber As String
End Structure
```

and here is the test method I'm using:

```
 Public Sub TestContactToString()

    Dim contact As New Contact

    contact.Address = "123 Main st."
    contact.FirstName = "Bob"
    contact.LastName = "Builder"
    contact.PhoneNumber = "613-828-1233"

    Dim unmanagedAddress As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(contact))

    Marshal.StructureToPtr(contact, unmanagedAddress, True)

    Dim result As String = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(unmanagedAddress)

    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(unmanagedAddress)
    unmanagedAddress = IntPtr.Zero

End Sub
```

Right now the result variable is only getting the first field in the structure "Address"...  It looks as thought the pointer many not have enough space allocated?  Wondering how I would go about getting the rest of the data into the string...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, yes, this is the expected outcome.  Marshal.PtrToStringUni() will terminate on an embedded zero, the string terminator for strings in the C language.  Which will be present in the struct since the strings won't fill the entire field.  And are generated by Marshal.StructureToPtr() because it assumes a C program will read the struct.

You used a cannon to kill a mosquito, use String.PadRight() instead.

Comment: Love the analogy! Not sure I understand what you mean though... string.PadRight on what exactly?  The result or the pointer?  Could you provide a small code sample?  Thank you, I really appreciate the adivce!

Comment: The strings.  Just make them long enough with that and concatenate them with the + operator.

Comment: Ok, so are you saying not to use marshal.PtrToStringUni and the pointer and just concatenate the data directly from the structure instead?

Comment: Yes.  And forget about the struct entirely.  Think string[] instead.  Could be a params array for example.

Comment: The trouble is we are getting the data back in an object from another service and this method needs to be generic enough to accept a number of different objects, this is just a small test I'm working with... Originally I had a method that uses reflection to get all of the fields from the object, pull the data out and put it back into a string.  The marshaling way just looked like it might be less code but it looks like I'll have to go back to my original solution.  Thank you so much for you help!